# Avdmanager not found

Tags: flutter, visual-studio, android-emulator, avd-manager, flutter-doctor

I am trying to run my first flutter app emulator, which is having complications  at various level, I have tried too much but could not make through it, here is what I have tried.

On trying to click on **Create Android Emulator** in Visual studio code, the dart extension shows following:-

[link to img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCc87.png)

I don't know why it is happening as on checking, it is present:-

[link to img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0UA1.png).

I would like to point out here that I am not able to understand what I have to put in `flutter --android-sdk {path}`.

Also on running `flutter doctor`, it shows the absence of visual studio despite the fact that I have it in place(that is why I could take the first screenshot). One thing I would like to point out here is that my vscode is in C drive while my `flutter-test` folder(which contains everything related to flutter) is in D drive:

[link to img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dihG.png)

Please help so that I can further follow along to create an android app. Also ask if any further information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know that having Android Studio Installed will solve the majority of issues caused.

**STEPS:**

- Clean out all your Flutter, Dart and Android installation
- Download Android Studio from [official](https://developer.android.com/studio) website (the latest version is ***Android Studio Electric Eel***)
- After the installation of Android Studio, open it and add the flutter and dart plugins
- Now download [flutter](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows) and follow the installation steps.
- After adding flutter, go to **Edit the system environment** on your PC and add **JAVA_HOME** variable with `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr`. Noticed I used `jbr` not `jre` because with **Android Studio Electric Eel** `jbr` replaced `jre`.
- Afterward, open new terminal and run `flutter doctor --android-licenses`

**WHAT DID WE DO ABOVE?**

We cleaned our installation and downloaded the latest Flutter version which has Dart downloaded automatically. Next, we Installed Android Studio Electric Eel which has Java and Android settings in-build. This way we solve 99% of the problems here:[image: problem image] The last thing is to create an Emulator using **Android Studio** not **VSC**.

For future help, please comment below. Bye